# Detect a user wrote a comment about an app

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way that you can track a user left a comment about your app at Play Store? What I'm looking for is to automatically detect it. I'd like my app to know whether the user actually left a comment or not. Something like a listener, but anyway I can use an external API if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any official API to work with the Play Store.

There are, though, many unofficial APIs out there; [This one](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) seems promising, if it's up to date. You can use it to grab all the comments on your app, then use the [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) to get the user Google ID, and compare their ID with the commentors IDs to check whether they have left a comment or not.

Comment: Its last release was in 2011, but probably this hasn't changed that much in terms of comments. I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: I hope it'll work :) If it doesn't just search for another API which lets you grab the comments.